# How to install Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, gpu-driver

How do I install Intel® HD Graphics 5500 on Ubuntu 15.04. I find installer for ubuntu 14.10 but don't work on this version.

Comment: They are already part of the install.  Intel has great Linux support.  If you are having the issue in which the "Details" window is showing the graphics as unknown, you just need to install a package to get them recognized see this question:   http://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-graphics-card-to-be-recognized-in-system-info

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't I need to install any Drivers for Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/306963/why-dont-i-need-to-install-any-drivers-for-ubuntu)

Comment: Yes, you're right. Show my graphic in "Details" window, but in "Additional Driver" show Unknown: Unknown, The device using an alternative driver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install drivers for an Intel HD Graphics?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87090/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-an-intel-hd-graphics)

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to install anything.
This is an integrated graphics chip.
The graphics driver is preinstalled.

Comment: I will upvote this as it is true enough, I think however the OP is running into the "graphic driver is showing as unknown issue"  see my comment to his question for more info......

Comment: @TrailRider - Thank you ! - it's not easy to help when nearly nothing is specified in a question - maybe you're correct with your comment on the question, especially  as the broadwell chips are quite 'fresh' ...

Comment: It is not just b/c it's a  Broadwell chip, this has been a long standing bug:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa-demos/+bug/914631 (since 2011) the bug report shows it as fixed but I had this issue still in 2012 so it likely still crops up for at, least some users.....