# How to install AMD Radeon HD7000 drivers for Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, radeon, amd-graphics

I searched on Google but everything I could find was about AMD removing the support for Ubuntu 16.04. Lots of people mentioned there is an open-source driver but I couldn't find it and I am not sure I can set it up even if I find it. So, it would be great if someone tells me how I can install the drivers for AMD Radeon HD7850 for Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: ...related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/306963/why-dont-i-need-to-install-any-drivers-for-ubuntu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Radeon Open Source Driver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/159586/how-to-install-radeon-open-source-driver)

Answer (score 0):

This is question is answered here. [How to install Radeon Open Source Driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159586/how-to-install-radeon-open-source-driver#277500)

Purge AMD catalyst

```
 sudo apt-get purge fglrx
```

and download `xserver-xorg-video-ati` make sure you have the ATI driver first `xf86-video-ati` (or let dpkg resolve it.)

Comment: Note link does not mention fgrlx16.04, edited while I was posting. And release notes in 16.04 say fglrx will be uninstalled and currently only the open source driver works. AMD is updating drives due to incompatibility with Linux kernel. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes#fglrx  and: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2016-March/016315.html But it seems beta is out there if you are not installing in your main working install. http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=amdgpu-pro-rx460&num=1