# How to find drivers for ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, 20.04, graphics

I'm new to Ubuntu. I am trying it in a VM from the past 2 months and I like it! I want to dual boot it alongside Windows. Now I know how to install it, but I don't know how to install drivers. So can anyone help me to find drivers?

Here are my comp's specs
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3610QM
8 GB DDR3 RAM
NVIDIA GeForce GT 630M
1 TB SSD
Model: ASUS K55VM

Comment: ...related:https://askubuntu.com/questions/306963/why-dont-i-need-to-install-any-drivers-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to find any external driver, Ubuntu will take care of it by default but there is one important thing to note:

Ubuntu also tend to use generic drivers and those will update every point release....

You should first try Ubuntu alongside windows and see if any problem even exist or not...

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are two commands, which will be your most used ones:

- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get upgrade

those two will keep your applications and drivers up to date.

It could happen that Ubuntu has problems with your gpu. These are the only drivers you really have to care about. The first time ubuntu starts, install the correct driver for your gpu.

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/

This website is for ubuntu 18.04, but works the same for 20.04

Hope I could help.